# AttributeError: module 'collections' has no attribute 'Iterator' python 3.10 django 2.0

Tags: python, django

Hello its a clone project but when ı try "python manage.py makemigrations" ım getting this error how can ı fix it?

requirements

```
django==2.0 django-ckeditor==5.4.0
django-cleanup==2.1.0    django-crispy-forms==1.7.2
django-js-asset==1.0.0
```

[this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sreR5.png)

[error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4pEFE.png)

Answer (score 5):

You are using a very old version of Django (we are currently in version 4.1.x!) which is incompatible with python3.10.

`Iterator` was moved from `collections` to `collections.abc` (I think in version 3.3).

In order to fix this issue you must either downgrade your python version to something before python3.3 (which is quite unfortunate I guess), or upgrade your django version (which might be very hard, depending on your application).

You can actaully see this change in a 4 year old commit in the django repo: https://github.com/django/django/commit/aba9763b5117494ca1ef1e420397e3845ad5b262.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks you for your help, I'll try my best, I'm a bit new to this stuff. If there is a problem, can I ask you a question again?

Comment: Of course, feel free to contact me :)

Comment: Hello ı tried with pyton 3.2 but It doesn't see django, I download django 2.0 and put it in the lib\site-package but still not working I also installed from cmd ı added new photo can you check?

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix that works for **python3.10**:

in file `/usr/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py`

Add this line of code:

```
from _collections_abc import Iterator
```

**Note**: The path might change

Answer (score 0):

Added:
`from _collections_abc import Iterable`

after

```
from _weakref import proxy as _proxy
```

It works for `python3.11`.